# Routing "Following list" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can go to  "http://localhost:3000/users/5/following" manually in my browser to see a paginated list of users I am following in my application

In my Navbar, I've linked <%= link_to content_tag(:li, "Watching"), user_path(@user) %> and I get /users/5 in the URL.

What Rails syntax should I add after  "user_path(@user)" to direct to /users/5/following?

My UserController for "following" looks like:

```
    def following
       @title = "Following"
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
       render 'show_follow'
    end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you have `following` as member in routes. Then following_user_path(user_id) should do the job. You can also run `rake routes` to inspect your routes.

Comment: Got a controller error and did following_user_path(@user) and worked! Thanks!